# how to assign dataProvider to DataGrid Dyanmically in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3

i done as follows

i have a method with brings data of particular table, as given my parameter to that method,

now i want to fetch data from corresponding table and it too list, and send back flex and form dynamically Grid & add dataprovider dynamically as for its corresponded table colomns in flex side ?

Remote objec(java  class)

```
 public List<List<String>> getMasterTableData(String name) 
 { 
  String designMaster = "tbl_design_master"+name;

  String masterTableName = "tbl_master"+name; 

  String[][] res ;

  List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

  try 
  {
   st = connection.createStatement();

   ResultSet rs1 = st.executeQuery("select * from "+designMaster);

   int len = 0;

   while(rs1.next())
   { len++; }

   ResultSet rs2 = st.executeQuery("select * from "+masterTableName);

   while(rs2.next())
   { 
    List<String>  ll = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i=1;i<=len; i++)
    {
     ll.add(rs2.getString(i));     
    }    
    list.add(ll);
   }   
  }
  catch (SQLException e) {   
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

  return list;
 }
```

flex code :

```
<mx:RemoteObject id="RO" destination="adminServiceImpl"> 
 <mx:method name="getMasterDesign" result="getMasterDesignRH(event)" fault="FH(event)" />
 <mx:method name="getMasterTableData" result="getMasterTableDataRH(event)" fault="FH(event)"/>
</mx:RemoteObject> 

 <mx:Script>
  <![CDATA[

  [Bindable] private var ac:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(); 

  public function init(Str:String):void
  {
   RO.getMasterDesign(Str);

   Application.application.selectedgridItem = Str;

   RO.getMasterTableData(Str);
  }

  private function getMasterDesignRH(event:ResultEvent):void
  {
   Application.application.designList = event .result as ArrayCollection; 

   var aColumns:Array = new Array();   

   for(var i:int=0; i< Application.application.designList.length; i++)
   { 
    var dgc:DataGridColumn = new DataGridColumn();

    dgc.headerText = Application.application.designList.getItemAt(i).colName; 

    //dgc.dataField = Application.application.designList.getItemAt(i).colName;

    aColumns.push(dgc);   
   }
   mainGrid.columns = aColumns;
  }
  private function getMasterTableDataRH(event:ResultEvent):void
  {
   ac = event.result as ArrayCollection; 

   mainGrid.dataProvider  = ac;  
  }  
  private function FH(event:FaultEvent):void{ 
   Alert.show(event.fault.faultString);  
  }


  ]]>
 </mx:Script>

  <mx:HBox width="100%" height="80%">
   <mx:DataGrid id="mainGrid" width="100%" height="100%" />
  </mx:HBox>
```

getMasterDesign is an ArrayCollection, which is filled with the column names and components to be displayed

Ex : getMasterDesign(emp) 
empMasterDesign table looks like as follows

```
colName    component 
--------------------
EmpName    textBox
empSal     textBox 
empDesi    ComboBox 

empMasterData:

empName | EmpSal | EmpDesi 
abc       1000     Cler## Heading ##ck 
xyz       2000     Manager
```

Now i want this create a Datagrid in flex dynamically by using its design & master data table in action script i done everyting , my dataGrid had formed as for his master design,but data is not showing ?

Comment: @ Amar: Hi, i know ur the one for me to assist in this StachOverflow,

please help me in this regards,
i want to create a grid, depending on it's table columns in flex by passing its corresponded table name to backend java class.

Comment: Have you configured the remote object properly? Are you calling the `init()` method at all? What does `getMasterDesign` return at the java end?

Comment: @Amar: Yes Amar. i got List<List>(list of list) from java to felx, but when i assing mainGrid.dataProvider  = ac, it's not displaying data in grid, 

is problem with dataField ? or with data assignment to datagrid ?

Comment: for datafield i brought indually a list with all comlumn names of its correnponding table from DB

Comment: Are you able to see any columns (even empty ones) at all? Can you post the structure/contents of the two responses?

Comment: @Amar : yah am getting List of List as 'AC 'data provider in Result Handler.

even my Table is Formed with exact data fields. 
but empty table without data(even aftr providing dataprovider to grid)

Comment: @Amar: getMasterDesign  is a ArrayCollection ,which fillled with the Colomns names & componet to be displayed

Ex : getMasterDesign(emp)  

empMasterDesign table looks like as follows

colName:  component
EmpName   textBox
empSal    textBox 
empDesi   ComboBox

empMasterData :


empName  |  EmpSal | EmpDesi
abc         1000     Clerck
xyz         2000     Manager


Now i want this create a Datagrid in flex dynamically by suing tis design & master data table in action script 

i done everyting , my dataGrid had formed as for his master design,but data is not showing ?

Comment: Please find below bit elobartely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set the `dataField` to the appropriate value. From the given data, it looks like `colName` field in the metadata and its corresponding name in the table are not the same. For example it is `EmpName` in the design and `empName` in the original table; none of the fields match - `empSal` vs `EmpSal`, `empDesi` vs `EmpDesi`. Fix that, assign colName to the dataField, and you should be good to go.